# Binding Combo Box using dictionary as datasource giving exception of 'System.Reflection.TargetException'

Tags: c#, xaml, dictionary, combobox, data-binding

Hi guys I am trying to populate my dynamic Combo Box with my dictionary. When I run my code like this:

C# Model

```
class QuestionModel
{
    public QuestionModel(Dictionary<string, string> Answers)
    {
        answers=Answers;
    }
    public Dictionary<string, string> answers { get; set; }
}
```

C# Dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, string> AnsStore = new Dictionary<string, string>();
AnsStore.Add("1", "Chess");
AnsStore.Add("2", "Darts");

questionCollection.Add(new QuestionModel(AnsStore));
```

Xaml

```
<ComboBox Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="QuestioncomboBox" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="25" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=answers}" />
```

My output of my Combo Box is:

> 1, Chess
>   2, Darts

So in order to get my Combo Box to just output the value and not the key

> Chess
>   Darts

I change my Xaml code to this:

Xaml

```
<ComboBox Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="QuestioncomboBox" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="25" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=answers}" SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value" />
```

But when I run my application and click in the Combo Box I get this exception.

> An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetException' occurred in mscorlib.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
>   Additional information: Object does not match target type.

What am I doing wrong and how can I correct my code to fix this?

Comment: It works fine for me. What type is your SelectedValue bound to?

Comment: its is bound to a string as shown in my code above for the model

Comment: No SelectedValue, not SelectedValuePath. The code you have posted works fine, so I can only assume something you omitted is wrong. SelectedValue seemed like the most obvious suggestion.

Comment: I was not using selected value? Sorry I am new to this should I use selected value and set it as my key

Comment: The fact that you are setting SelectedValuePath made me assume that you would be using SelectedValue to drive the selected combo item. I was also assuming that that might be what is giving you your type problem. Obviously not if you're not using it. Sorry.

Comment: strange that it works for you but in windows 8.1 it doesn't work for me. It only works when I remove selected value path and display item path. so you just see the values without keys in yours

Comment: Correct. And adding SelectedValue="2" correctly selects "Darts"